# Run iOS app without using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to find a way to automatize the running of some tests on iOS.

Is there any way I can start an app on the device without the use of Xcode (by using a script, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the tool below which does exactely what I need:
https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap

Comment: Unfortunately, that project is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not solve your problem right away: But you might want to look at how RubyMotion solves this problem. It compiles files from the command line, installs them in the simulator, and also installs apps on the device. 
I couldn't figure how it works, but maybe you can.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on my [blog](http://mobiledevtest.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/ios-how-to-run-application-from-command.html)...

fruitstrap is based on gdb-arm-apple-darwin (not used anymore on xcode 5).

Install:
xcode 5 use debugserver so you need to use: [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller).

Run app: [idevice-app-runner](https://github.com/crackleware/idevice-app-runner)